# Prove a set is at most countable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that for each $\lambda$ in a set $\Lambda$ we have a positive real number $a_\lambda > 0$. Suppose also that for any natural number $n$ and any $\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n \in \Lambda$ we have
$$ \sum_{ i = 1 }^n a_{ \lambda_i } < 1 $$
Prove that the set $\Lambda$ is at most countable.

I know that every $0 < a_{ \lambda_i } < 1$. I was wondering if I could get a hint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: How many $\lambda_i$ can there be in the interval $[\frac12, 1)$? How many in the interval $[\frac13, \frac12)$? $[\frac14, \frac13)$? In general, how many can there be in the interval $[\frac1{n+1},\frac1n)$?

What happens when you take the union of all those intervals and add all those numbers up?